# Replace image with other image

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new in android, so I still learning simple things. :)

I have images (*.jpg) in directory named "drawable-xhdpi" (only there). I can see the R.java file contain these images and set them a corresponding hex value.
I add my image view to the XML file:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a1" />
```

So, After setting this, I can see it in the begining of the emulator.
Now, I want to change it to be "a2.jpg" in code. I have the string path of an image file described above (for example: "a2"). therefore, I used:

```
ImageView (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("a2", "drawable", getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(resId);
```

But it's fail. the image isn't replaced by the other image. and it doesn't matter if I wrote the above lines in the OnCreate method of the activity, or in some method which respond to android:OnClick.

I looked the previous answer in the forum, but still can't find - what have I missed?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your new jpeg is in drawables, use setImageResource(R.drawable.a2)

Comment: But the probelm here that I'm limiting the available file for this. The activity shall not knows the file name, it just accepts it from other standard java class, or even from text file.

Comment: If its not in your drawable folder, then getDrawable isn't the way to get it.  Instead you want to get a Bitmap for it via BitmapFactory.decodeFile.  You only load drawables like that for files that are in the drawable directory.

Comment: I'll calrify my explanation: all image files are in drawable folder. in Activity class, after button pressed, I don't know the specific image shall be presented. the activity is send message to another java class (which the activity doesn't know where it get the file names, ofcourse), and accept as answer the file name of the image to present. then the activity shall use this file name to get the source (in my above example: a2, but there're more than 50 options...). the thing I failed to execute is how to get the source from string.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using Drawable resources at all, you should be using assets.  The purpose of resources is for when using a small set of predefined items.  If you don't know the id at compile time, it shouldn't be using a Drawable resource.  Looking things up by name is the purpose of Assets.  Now if the 2 classes are int he same package and can just pass a long resourceID, that's fine.  But your problem is you're using the wrong mechanism here.

Comment: OK, I'll read about it. new thing to learn. :)